# Term for members of a class that are not inherited

Tags: terminology, object-oriented

Is there an explicit term for a member of a class that is not inherited from any parent class?

```
class Vehicle {
    int weight;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    int numDoors;
}

Car car = new Car();
car.weight = 10000; // weight is an "inherited member"
car.numDoor = 4; // what's the term for numDoor?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a [member variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable). If you want to specify that it is not inherited, I suppose you could call it '[noninherited](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noninherited) member variable'. Wiktionary lists this as a term in computing.